# Python issues scraping certificate data from a list of URLs

Tags: python, sql-server, web-scraping, ssl-certificate, grequests

I've made a `get_certificate` method to scrape all certificate data from a list of URLs, but my issue is that the 5 URLs get added to the database, but the certificate information from 1 of the URLs are duplicated.

Here is also a image that shows the duplicate inserted data [Sql data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZbG4.png)

> How do I scrape the data for each url?

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import socket
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import ssl
import OpenSSL
import requests
import grequests

timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

#Contains 5 URLs
List = open("C:\\Users\\Farzad\\Desktop\\hosts.txt").read().splitlines()

rs = (grequests.get(url) for url in List)

requests = grequests.map(rs)


def get_certificate(host, port=443):
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port))
    sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=host)
    der_cert = sock.getpeercert(True)
    sock.close()
    return ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(der_cert)


for response in requests:
    certificate = get_certificate(response.url.replace("http://www.", "").replace("https://www.", "").replace("/", "").replace("https:", ""))
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate)
    Pubkeyobj = x509.get_pubkey()
    pubKeyString = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, Pubkeyobj)


pubkey = b'\n'.join(pubKeyString.splitlines()[1:-1])
keylength = str(Pubkeyobj.bits())


certvalidfrom = datetime.strptime(x509.get_notBefore().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
certvalidtill = datetime.strptime(x509.get_notAfter().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')


extensions = (x509.get_extension(i) for i in range(x509.get_extension_count()))
extension_data = {e.get_short_name(): str(e) for e in extensions}


subj = str(x509.get_subject().CN)
subjCN = str(x509.get_subject().CN)
subjAlt = extension_data[b'subjectAltName']
serial = str(x509.get_serial_number())
issuerCN = str(x509.get_issuer().CN)
sign = str(x509.get_signature_algorithm())


for response in requests:
    con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-THV2IDL;'
                      'Database=host;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = con.cursor()

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO host.dbo.certificate (host, ssubject, CommonName, AlternativeNames, PublicKey, SerialNumber, [KeyLength(BITS)], Validfrom, Validtill, [Issuer(CN)], CSA, Timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
          (response.url, subj, subjCN, subjAlt, pubkey, serial, keylength, certvalidfrom, certvalidtill, issuerCN, sign, timestamp))

    con.commit()
```

Comment: Try combining your two `for response in requests` loops into one and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @JackFleeting Just did however same issue

Comment: Somehow it fixed after entering all the code except for the `get_certificate` method inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, it's frequently an issue of deciding what properly belongs inside and outside a particular loop. Glad it worked for you.